# Beginners PHP Question: What the difference between $_POST and $_FILES?

Tags: php

Beginners PHP Question: What the difference between $_POST and $_FILES?

PHP.net says:

$_POST is an associative array of **variables passed** to the current script via the HTTP POST method

$_FILES is an associative array of **items uploaded** to the current script via the HTTP POST method

Could anyone explain what this means in practical terms?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Both **$_POST** and **$_FILES** are so called in php "superglobals". They are predefined variables(arrays), which means they are available in all scopes throughout a script. There is no need to declare them to access them within functions or methods.

[$_POST](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.post.php) contains all the data from forms (except files)

[$_FILES](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php) contains all files sent to server via forms (only from `<input type="file" />`)

Answer (score 2):

$_POST and $_FILES are called 'superglobals'. 
$_POST contains the data from the form without displaying it in the url address. So it's safe in posting data.
But for files you have to use $_FILES, because files can not be posted using $_POST.

Hope it will work for you.

Answer (score 0):

Both $_POST and $_FILES are so called in php "superglobals". 
They are predefined variables(arrays), which means they are available in all scopes throughout a script. 
There is no need to declare them to access them within functions or methods.

$_POST contains all the data from forms (except files)

$_FILES contains all files sent to server via forms
 (only from )